# login_table matching query does not exist

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

DoesNotExist at /login1/ login_table matching query does not exist.

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response
from django.core.context_processors import request, csrf
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect
from login.models import login_table

def login(request):
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    firstname = request.POST.get('firstname')
    lastname = request.POST.get('lastname')
    email = request.POST.get('email')
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    password = request.POST.get('password')
    gender = request.POST.get('test')
    phonenumber = request.POST.get('phone')
    country = request.POST.get('country')
    data = login_table(first_name=firstname,last_name=lastname, email=email, user_name=username, password=password, gender=gender, phone=phonenumber,country=country)
    data.save()
    return render_to_response('log.html',c)

def login1(request):
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    us = request.POST.get('user_name')
    pa = request.POST.get('password')
    u = login_table.objects.get(user_name='user_name')
    p = login_table.objects.get(password='password')
    if us == u and pa == p:
        response = render_to_response('content.html',c)
    else:
        response = render_to_response('failed.html', c)
    return response
```

It shows login_table matching query does not exist error message. What is the error?

Comment: Like the error says, it is likely that the login_table does not exists or it is named differently.

Comment: Don't write your own login system like this, it's insecure. Django comes with an [auth app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/). Use it.

Comment: @LoreV that is not what the error says, what is says is that there is no entry    in the `login_table` matching a query. I guess the query in question is `u = login_table.objects.get(user_name='user_name')`